# What would have happened if Luke hadn't brought his weapon into the cave with him?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

As I was reading this question ([In The Empire Strikes Back, what is the significance of Luke seeing his own face in Vader's helmet?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9621/in-the-empire-strikes-back-what-is-the-significance-of-luke-seeing-his-own-face?rq=1)) and someone mentioned that, had Luke decided to bring his lightsaber into the cave in Dagobah with him, his imaginary fight with Vader would have had a very different outcome.

> "Your weapon," Yoda reproved, "you won't need it"

**Is there any canon (or Legends) explanation of what would have happened if Luke had actually followed Yoda's advice?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Shamelessly stealing [from my own answer on Movies.SE](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/1015/235):

**Lucas explains this on the Empire Strikes Back DVD commentary.**

Had Luke gone into the cave with no weapons, **he would not have met Vader in there**.

P.S. Yoda said that what is in there is "only what you take with you" - Luke takes his weapons, he's aggressive - he's making the same mistakes Anakin did 25 years before, and could end up the same way. Note that it is Luke who activates his lightsaber first, not Vader - Luke is the aggressor.

Comment: Could you add a quote from the DVD commentary?

Comment: @SQB - I don't have the quote handy, but I can confirm that Lucas says it.  Luke's decision to bring his weapons into the cave was the reason he saw Vader.

Comment: @SQB - I'll try to pull a <>Richard on this, but it'll be a big "maybe". I saw the commentary at someone else's house, wasn't my DVD so I can't rewatch at will.

Comment: DVK thanks, I'll re-watch the commentary and (may take me a while) will get a quote for @SQB at some point ;)